# xslt sorting by child element count

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I am trying to create an html table by querying on an xml document. I am using xslt.

Here is the problem. "parent" node contains many "child" nodes. I have to o/p a table that contains @name of parent and count of "child" nodes in sorted order(descending). So I am doing

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="parent[count(child) &gt; 3]">

  <html>
   <table border="1">
      <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:sort select="{count(child)}" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <tr>
        <td><b><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></b></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="count(child)" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each> 
   </table>
   </html>

   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="text()" />
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the html however the only problem is I am not getting it in sorted order by count of child elements. I suspect I am using count incorrectly xsl:sort? Can you help?

Input xml

```
<outer>
<parent name="abc" attr1="22664136" attr2="647500">
<child percentage="11">aaa</child>
<child percentage="35">bbb</child>
<child percentage="50">ccc</child>
</parent>

<parent name="ggg" attr1="3249136" attr2="28750"/>

<parent name="ghi" attr1="29183032" attr2="2381740">
<child2>
<name>ppp</name>
<attr1>1507241</attr1>
</child2>
</parent>


<parent name="qwe" attr1="10342899" attr2="1246700"/>

<parent name="lkj" attr1="65647" attr2="440">
<child percentage="100">jjj</child>
</parent>

</outer>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it was intentional, but the input document you provided doesn't have any matching templates, apart from the text elements: none of your `parent` elements have `count(child) > 3`.

Comment: @abc Dimitre's solution is a complete and correct answer to your problem, so please mark his as correct. I only fixed one mistake in yours, which didn't even solve the initial sorting issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are numerous mistakes in the provided XSLT code!**

The biggest problem is here:

> ```
>     <xsl:for-each select=".">
>       <xsl:sort select="{count(child)}" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
>       <tr>
>         <td><b><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></b></td>
>         <td><xsl:value-of select="count(child)" /></td>
>       </tr>
>     </xsl:for-each>
> ```

This will not perform any meaningful sort, because the node-set of the nodes to be sorted contains only one node -- the current node.

**The next problem is here**:

```
<xsl:sort select="{count(child)}" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```

There shouldn't be any AVT in any `select` attribute of an XSLT instruction -- you need to remove the curly braces.

**The 3rd problem is that the sort is specified too-late -- inside the template mathcing `parent`.** A parent doesn't have any children that themselves have `child` children.

**Solution**: Correcting all major problems, discussed above, one may arrive at the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:for-each select="parent">
                    <xsl:sort select="count(child)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                            </b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(child)" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<outer>
    <parent name="abc" attr1="22664136" attr2="647500">
        <child percentage="11">aaa</child>
        <child percentage="35">bbb</child>
        <child percentage="50">ccc</child>
    </parent>
    <parent name="ggg" attr1="3249136" attr2="28750"/>
    <parent name="ghi" attr1="29183032" attr2="2381740">
        <child2>
            <name>ppp</name>
            <attr1>1507241</attr1>
        </child2>
    </parent>
    <parent name="qwe" attr1="10342899" attr2="1246700"/>
    <parent name="lkj" attr1="65647" attr2="440">
        <child percentage="100">jjj</child>
    </parent>
</outer>
```

**the wanted-sorted result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <table border="1">
      <tr>
         <td><b>abc</b></td>
         <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><b>lkj</b></td>
         <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><b>ggg</b></td>
         <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><b>ghi</b></td>
         <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><b>qwe</b></td>
         <td>0</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Good catch seeing that the for-each/sort was on a set of size 1. Yours should be marked as correct!

Comment: @btlachance: Thanks. Please, tell the OP :)

Comment: @Dimitre I figured that out before reading the answer. But I marked yours as correct now. Hope you are happy :)

Comment: @abc: I am happy that you are happy :) +1 for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Almost. You don't need the curly braces around your `xsl:sort select="..."`
Your for-each would then look like:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".">
  <xsl:sort select="count(child)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
  <tr>
    <td><b><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></b></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(child)" /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Edit: Just as an added bit of information, you only use curly braces on literal, result elements. [From the XSLT2.0 spec on attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-attribute-value-template):

> The following example creates an img result element from a photograph
>   element in the source; the value of the src and width attributes are
>   computed using XPath expressions enclosed in attribute value
>   templates:
>
> ```
> <xsl:variable name="image-dir" select="'/images'"/>
> <xsl:template match="photograph">
>   <img src="{$image-dir}/{href}" width="{size/@width}"/>
> </xsl:template>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, so I may be misremembering this, but I believe that count(child) should be count(child::node()).

Comment: that threw an error: " XPath syntax error at char 6 on line 10 in {count(child::node}:
Unknown axis name: "